# ember js DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray content

Tags: ember.js

```
AppController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
cat_id: ''
subcat_data: (->
  App.Subcategory.find({ parent_id: @get("cat_id") })
).property('cat_id').cacheable()

categorySub: (->
 result = Ember.A()
 for category in this.toArray()
    @set('cat_id', category.id)
    @sub = @get("subcat_data")
    console.log @sub
    result.pushObject({
      category: category
      subcategories: @sub.toArray()
    })

result.toArray()
).property('@subcat_data', '@each')
```

Now in console.log @sub display the content of zero objects

DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray:ember768> { query={...}, content=[0], store=, more...}

But when i check in firebug DOM it shows the content of objects 
  content [17, 18]

What i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Ember-data`, the content of an `ControllerArray` is not filled right away, when you ask for its content through the console.log, Ember-data returns a `Promise`, an empty object, `RecordArray`, whose content will be filled at some point in the future. By the time you check the content in the DOM, the content is already filled. A better way to validate this is to call console.log only when the content is filled.

```
contentDidChange: function() {
  console.info(this.get('content'));
}.observes('content.isLoaded')
```